# IllegalMonitorStateException being thrown on synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency

I am learning multithreading in java. Now I have to print 1 2 3 1 2 3... from three different threads. I know other solutions exist, but i need to understand why the exception is being thrown..
As per oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html it is thrown when wait or notify is called without owning the monitor.
I want to know if synchronization is on Main object, why it is not being owned.
Here is my code

```
class ThreadA implements Runnable {
    Main main;
    Object o = new Object();

    ThreadA(Main m) {
        this.main = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (main) {
            while (main.val == 1) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                main.val = 2;
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            notifyAll();
        }

    }

}

class ThreadB implements Runnable {

    Main main;
    Object o = new Object();

    ThreadB(Main m) {
        this.main = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (main) {
            while (main.val == 2) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                main.val = 3;
                try {

                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

}

class ThreadC implements Runnable {
    Main main;
    Object o = new Object();

    ThreadC(Main m) {
        this.main = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (main) {
            while (main.val == 3) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                main.val = 1;
                try {

                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

}

public class Main {
    volatile static int val = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main m = new Main();
        Thread A = new Thread(new ThreadA(m), "TA");
        Thread B = new Thread(new ThreadB(m), "TB");
        Thread C = new Thread(new ThreadC(m), "TC");

        A.start();
        B.start();
        C.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to put the entire body of a thread's `run()` method inside a `synchronized` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It should be main.wait() and main.notify()